# UIImageView autoresize programmatically

Tags: iphone-5, autoresize

I'm trying to align an imageView at the bottom of my UIViewController, but on iPhone 5 simulator it isn't aligned on the bottom.

I've tried to put an imageView at the bottom of the storyboard and it is aligned correctly so I guess I miss something in my code.

Any advice?

Thanks,
e.

```
imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 64)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
imageView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: you want this image to be as tall as the screen is, yes? are you using AutoLayout, b.t.w.?

Comment: I want the image to be at the bottom of the screen, its height is 64. Autolayout option is on!

Answer (score 1):

got it, used

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[xmlView]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(xmlView)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the Frame Size like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-64, 320, 64)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Hope this will help.